# How to solo Gold Fury?

Tags: smite

Which gods are best suited for soloing gold fury?

Do I need to be at a specific level?

Any generic/additional tips or items that will help?

Comment: I haven't played smite in quite some time, so I'm not sure what changed, but I was able to reliably solo gold fury at lvl 12 as most of the jungle gods (main Arachne), using the typical jungler items. (bumba, some lifesteal, etc)

Answer (score 1):

ADCs are best for soloing. You do not need to be at a specific level since gold fury spawns at a certain time every game. Bumba's mask and lifesteal are good items as well as wrath to prevent a enemy from stealing the kill or if your on low health.

Comment: unless they build lifesteal an ADC usually doesn't compare to a jungler when fighting jungle bosses.

Comment: You really should have at least 1 life-steal item as ADC

Comment: This sentence doesn't quite make sense: "You do not need to be at a specific level since gold fury spawns at a certain time every game." So, what you're saying is that if I'm behind and, for whatever reason, only level 5 as Thor, I can solo the Gold Fury?

Comment: You can fight it whenever you want as long as it has spawned I'm not talking about actually killing the gold fury

Comment: Thanks.  Wrath really does help get the kill when team mates or enemies attempt to steal the kill.