# Does ADC strictly mean Hunter?

Tags: terminology, smite

I understand that ADC (an abbreviation of Attack Damage Carry) is a term that came from other MOBAs.  In League of Legends it appears that the term is an **[old term since replaced](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/ADC)** with Marksman, Assassin and Fighter to refer to specific classes of champions.  In the article linked there is a list of definitive ADC champions.

I've been told that in Smite ADC refers *generally* to Hunters.  What does *generally* mean?  I've seen this *general* scope used here:

> [ADC: Pretty much always a Hunter, ...](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/219863/101016)

and here:

> [Attack Damage Carry. A term generated from other MOBAs, generally used to speak about Hunters, ...](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Common_Terms)

Does that mean ***all*** Hunters are considered ADC?  Or is there more to this?  I notice that ADC may also apply to Mages:

> [Carry - Player who generally stays in the long/duo lane (see Long Lane) together with the Support (see Support). Usually played by a Hunter or a Mage. Also known as "ADC".](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Common_Terms)

Additionally, AD in Smite seems to translate as physical gods.  Does this not apply to ADC in Smite (i.e. both physical and magical gods can be considered ADC)?

I ask because there are many guides as well as **[answers on this site](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/267466/101016)** that refer to ADC in the context of Smite

1. **Exactly which gods are considered ADC?**
2. **Does ADC really mean ONLY AND ALL Hunters?**

Comment: Very first result in google tells you exactly what this is.

Comment: @frank - result shows me ADC is generally Hunter, but in same article says carry is hunter or mage.

Comment: @frank - from here: http://smite.gamepedia.com/Common_Terms (see ADC and see Carry definitions)

Comment: So if there's some confusion, why not ask for clarification, instead of the straight definition?  That's easily found, and shows no research at all on your part. Pointing to a source, and asking for clarification does a much better job of that.

Comment: @frank - er, that is exactly what I have done.. asked for clarification *Does that mean all Hunters are considered ADC?*.  As you can see, I am trying to clarify if I am able to just apply all Hunters when it comes to "ADC" in guides and other answers.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Smite Gamepedia](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Common_Terms)

> Attack Damage Carry. A term generated from other MOBAs, generally used to speak about [Hunters](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Hunter), gold and item dependent gods that can be quite dangerous at later stages of the game.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this definition (see my comments in the OP).  I don't understand the wording "generally used to speak about Hunters".  Also, further down the page it confirms that the Carry is either Hunter or Mage, and says this role is generally referred to as ADC.

Comment: @camelCase do mages do physical damage in Smite? because every mage character I've ever played deals magic damage, and ADC stands for attack damage carry

Comment: @Dragonrage - yes all mages are magical, and all hunters are physical.  But if you see the rest of the article (scroll down to Carry) and you will see: *Player who generally stays in the long/duo lane (see Long Lane) together with the Support (see Support). Usually played by a Hunter or a Mage. Also known as "ADC".*

Comment: Mage and Guardian autoattacks are magical, I believe. Anyway, this answer does not clarify anything. Is Kali an ADC? She's gold and item dependent, and carries. But she's also the jungle pick and isn't a hunter.

Answer (score 1):

In Smite there is no "Attack Damage" stat so the term is not literal, you can consider it like an approximation to original.

The ADC term is referred to the role, not the class so **NO, ADC do not strictly mean Hunter**, but yes usually the gods who best fit in this roll are hunters.

Comment: So... does this mean that "ADC" is mostly equivalent to "carry"? Or, are you trying to say that the term "ADC" should be deprecated and people should just use terms like "physical", "magical" and "carry" to describe these sorts of gods?

Comment: Ended, I heard many times the term "carry" and I also use it asiduos. Also "ADC" may not be technically correct but I don't think is something to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

An ADC is a term used to describe a ranged god that deals most damage from auto attacks. All hunters can be played as an ADC as well as some mages like Sol and Freya.

Answer (score 1):

An ADC in Smite is a god who mostly uses basic attacks to deal damage. Just as the other answers stated this doesn't have to be strictly gods from the Hunter class.

Although most players pick a hunter in the ADC role. 
As @SmedleyDSlap stated this could be a mage like Sol Freya or Chronos. And there are certain magical basic attack gods that counter the hunters.

But it could be a ranged Assassin as well there was a moment in time(Can't remember what Season it was) that Mercury was considered a viable pick as ADC.

A tip for the future. Go on twitch and watch some pro players like Barraccudda or Zapman who is a ADC. And ask questions in their chat. They have much more knowledge of their role and the game in general.

Also it is not forbidden to experiment in the game. But I advise to keep it with hunters and mages.

Comment: @camelCase I do also recommend to stick with the hunters if just started with the game/role